# Single product page not displaying on mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, mern

i am trying to make a single product page in my mern stack project, yesterday i designed my desktop view and mobile view succesfully and no error where there.
Today when i try to view the product page the product details not showing on the mobile view but its showing on the desktop and view no errors showing in the console.

only the header and footer layout is displaying, i believe that its not a server side problem because all details are shown in desktop view.

[image: screen shot]

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Layout from './../components/Layout/Layout.js';
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import toast from "react-hot-toast";
import axios from "axios";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import "./productpage.css"
import { useCart } from "../context/cart";

const ProductPage = () => {
    const [product, setProducts] = useState([]);
    //const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [cart, setCart] = useCart()
    const params = useParams();
    const [pid, setId] = useState("");
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
    const [mrp, setMrp] = useState("");
    const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
    const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState();
    const [Quantity, setQuantity] = useState(1)

    const getSingleProduct = async () => {
        try {
            const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/v1/product/product-page/${params.id}`);
            setProducts(data);
            setId(data.product._id);
            setName(data.product.name);
            setDescription(data.product.description);
            setImages(data.product.images);
            setMrp(data.product.mrp);
            setSelectedImage(data.product.images[0]);
            

            if (data.success) {
                // Do something if needed
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            toast.error("Something went wrong in getting category");
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getSingleProduct(params.id);
    }, [params.id]); 

    return (
        <Layout>
            <div className="pdiv">
                <Row xs={1} md={2} className="g-4 row row-cols-md-2 row-cols-1">
                    <Col className="colone">
                        <img src={`http://localhost:3000/uploads/${selectedImage}`} alt="" style={{ width: "80%" }}></img>
                        <div className="grid">
                            {images.map((image, index) => (
                                <div key={index} className="simg" >
                                        <img
                                            src={`http://localhost:3000/uploads/${image}`}
                                            alt=""
                                            className="cimg"
                                            // style={{ width: "50%" ,border: "1px solid black"}}
                                            onClick={() => setSelectedImage(image)} // Update selected image on click
                                        />
                                   
                                </div>
                            ))}
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                    <Col className="coltwo">
                        <h2 className="modln">{name}</h2>
                        <h3 className="mmrp">₹{mrp}.00</h3>
                        <label className="mrlabel">Sales Tax Included</label><br />
                        <label className="qtylabel">Quantity</label>
                        <input
                            type="number"
                            min={1}
                            defaultValue={1}
                            className="qty"
                            style={{ display: "block" }}
                            onChange={(e) => {
                                const newQuantity = parseInt(e.target.value); // Parse the value to an integer
                                setQuantity(newQuantity);
                            }}
                        />
                        <button className="addtc" onClick={() => {
                            const finalqty = [pid, name, images, mrp, Quantity];
                            setCart([...cart, finalqty]);
                        }}>Add to Cart</button><br />
                        <button className="buy">Buy Now</button>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row xs={1} md={2} className="g-4 row row-cols-md-2 row-cols-1">
                    <pre className="descpre">{description}</pre>
                </Row>

            </div>
        </Layout>
    );
}

export default ProductPage;
```

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 2000px) {
    .pdiv {
        margin: 60px 80px;
    }
    .grid{
        display: grid;
        margin-top: 20px;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(5,80px);
        grid-auto-rows: 80px;
        column-gap: 1rem;
    }
    .cimg{
        width:50%;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .simg{
        margin-right: -85px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .cimg:hover{
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgb(227, 227, 227);
    }
        
    

    .descpre {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 1.6;
        align-self: flex-start;
        margin-left: 10%;
        margin-top: 65px;
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    .mmrp {
        color: rgb(201, 8, 8);
        margin-top: 50px;
        margin-bottom: 2px;
    }
    .qtylabel{
        margin-top: 30px;
    }

    .qty {
        margin-top: 8px;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        width: 80px;
        padding-left: 15px;
        height: 45px;
    }

    .addtc {
        color: white;
        background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        border-radius: 4px;
        border-bottom: 0px;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        border-right: 0px;
        border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        margin-top: 25px;
        height: 50px;
        width: 80%;
    }

    .buy {
        margin-top: 15px;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        background-color: rgb(163, 255, 24);
        border-radius: 4px;
        border-bottom: 0px;
        border-right: 0px;
        border-color: rgb(163, 255, 24);
        height: 50px;
        width: 80%;
    }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .shcard{
        width: 380px;
    }
    .grid{
        display: grid;
        margin-top: 20px;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(5,80px);
        grid-auto-rows: 80px;
        column-gap: 1rem;
    }
    .cimg{
        width:50%;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .simg{
        margin-right: -85px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .cimg:hover{
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgb(227, 227, 227);
    }
    .pdiv {
        margin-top: 40px;
    }

    .colone {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .coltwo {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;

        .qty {
            align-self: flex-start;
            margin-left: 10%;
            width: 80px;
            height: 45px;
        }


    }


    .addtc {
        color: white;
        background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        border-radius: 4px;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        border-bottom: 0px;
        border-right: 0px;
        border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        margin-top: 25px;
        height: 50px;
        width: 80%;
    }

    .buy {
        margin-top: -10px;
        background-color: rgb(163, 255, 24);
        border-radius: 4px;
        border-bottom: 0px;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        border-right: 0px;
        border-color: rgb(163, 255, 24);
        height: 50px;
        width: 80%;
    }

    .modln {
        align-self: flex-start;
        margin-left: 10%;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .mmrp {
        align-self: flex-start;
        margin-left: 10%;
        color: rgb(201, 8, 8);
        margin-bottom: 2px;
    }
    .mrlabel{
        align-self: flex-start;
        margin-left: 10%;
    }
    .qtylabel{
        align-self: flex-start;
        margin-left: 10%;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .descpre {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 1.6;
        align-self: flex-start;
        margin-left: 10%;
        margin-top: 65px;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}
```